# "open with" for text file fails

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm writing a simple text editor and would like it to be an option for "open with" when I click on a .txt file in the file browser.  As I read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#receiving-data-activity) all I should need to do is add an intent filter to the manifest file for this to happen.

I've modified my manifest adding the action.SEND intent-filter as shown below but only chrome and firefox show up in the "open with" dialog when a .txt file is clicked in the file browser.  I've tried "text/*" as well as "text/plain".  Is there something else I need to do??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.kana_tutor.notes">

    <!-- needed before API 26 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/notes_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE:** As @blackapps suggested in his comment below, the fix was to change ".action.SEND"" to ".action.VIEW".  I had suppress an error about not having a URL and my filter ended up as:

```
    <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: And if the file manager shares a txt file... Is your app with it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to accomplish -- although you said it better.  No -- I only see firefox and chrome.

Comment: @blackapps -- That's what clicking on the file does, right?  But good point.  No -- I see a bunch of apps -- not including firefox and chrome but including email, android beam, bluetooth, wi-fi direct -- but not my app.

Comment: .SEND ==> .VIEW

Comment: @blackapps -- That worked -- thanks.